# DIY 3D printer Z-axis problems

Tags: diy-3d-printer, z-axis, ramps

So I have a homebuilt 3D printer. I was testing the axes and all of that, suddenly the Z-axis stopped working.

I changed its connection to a different axis, and it's working, but when I bring it back to its original Z-axis port on the RAMPS, it doesn't move. I've adjusted the pot on the A4988 drivers, tried almost three of them, but still it wouldn't move.

What's the problem? Is it the controller issue or what? I've bought two RAMPS boards, first one 1.4, similar issue, the hotend port stopped working, and now RAMPS 1.5, Z-axis stopped working, although initially, they all worked great.

Comment: You have tagged the question with "G-Code" but don't mention it in your question. Please explain how the tag is relevant to the question.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Have you unplugged steppers when the board and steppers were being powered? P.S. do note the RAMPS shields are a little outdated, you have better options out there.